# eth_estimategas strange behaviour in Metamask

Tags: solidity, metamask, hardhat

I'm running Hardhat and testing with Metamask and found something strange in the Hardhat console output. This happens when I go to Metamask and select my contract's token, then click "send", then enter the destination address, at this point Metamask calls my Hardhat node's eth_estimateGas function:

```
eth_estimateGas
  Contract call:       mycontract#transfer
  From:                0x0000.....
  To:                  0x0000.....
  Value:               0 ETH

  Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'Invalid amount'
      at mycontract.someFunction (contracts/mycontract.sol:584)
      at mycontract.transfer (contracts/mycontract.sol:603)
```

As you can see it calls my transfer function, which checks the amount and reverts with "Invalid amount" if it's zero, which it is because I haven't entered the amount to transfer yet in Metamask.

What I don't understand is why it's calling mycontract.someFunction also. This is an external function that is never called anywhere in mycontract.

If I change the function name of someFunction then a different function is called instead. Maybe it's just calling the first function in the bytecode or something. I don't understand this behaviour, can someone enlighten me?